# Preload the next route then change it in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loader

I'm using Angular 1 to create a simple application with a few views, and a lot of content (images + text) in each view. I'm trying to do a loading-bar like [this website](https://www.rga.com/). (or the one on Youtube)

Which means:

- clicking on a link to go to the next view
- staying on the current view while next view is loading (data + images), with a loading bar
- showing the next view when it's fully loaded

I checked a lot of modules, especially angular-loading-bar, but I can't figure out how to:

- Make it work BEFORE the page is loaded
- get the percentage of loading (to have a bar to shows the real one)

Do you have any idea? I've seen a lot of websites doing that, but I can't find any articles that explains how to do it.

thanks

Comment: Why are you wanting to show the loading bar before you change? Would you not be getting the data after a state change?

Comment: This *feels like* a case where the understanding of Angular mechanics doesn't match up with the requirements.  Angular doesn't modify the DOM directly, so "pre-loading images" doesn't fit into the list of problems that angular is designed to solve.

Comment: @Chris I want the entire page to be loaded before it's displayed (and not have a flash when image is loading for exemple), and while waiting I want to stay on the current page (as on Youtube).

Comment: @Claies I'm not necessarily looking to preload images, it's more like loading the next view while staying on the current one. I've seen some explanation about loading the page in ajax then display it, but I can't figure out how

Comment: I would say that using ng-cloak or a ng-show/ng-hide would be a better solution to what you're describing. Loading your image locations via an HTTP call and then showing the page once you have the full collection is how i would approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success by writing a service that tracks the Angular router for load changes and emits values based off that.

You can hook onto router load and finish events by injecting the router into your service and calling `setUpLocationChangeListener` on it, which allows you to hook onto the Observable at `router.events`, e.g:

```
// loading.service.ts

this.router.setUpLocationChangeListener();

let routeChangeEvent = this.router.events;
routeChangeEvent
    .filter(() => event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationStart) // these types can be imported from @angular/router
    .subscribe(() => /*emit your own events from here*/)
```

This will let you hook onto router load events. Unfortunately, these are not determinate; there is no way to get the loading progress off of an Angular route change.

You can inject the service into a component that has a load bar and set up logic to display loading from there.

As far as tracking an AJAX call, the Angular `Http` service does not currently allow for tracking progress. This package is a nice little wrapper to fix that: [angular-progress-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-http). It stays identical to the normal `Http` service but allows optional tracking for progress events, which are a percentage of 0 to 100. Your load bar would need to be able to interperet these values (the official Angular Material loading bar works well).

Using this package, you can add methods on your `LoadingService` for components to call to start and end load events and progress, which in turn your loading-bar component can listen to.

extremely vague example:

```
// loading.service.ts:
export class LoadingService {

  public onLoadChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(router: Router) { /* subscribe to load events like above */ }


  public updateProgress(progress): void {
        this.onProgressChange.emit(progress.percentage);
  }

  public endLoad(): void {
        this.onLoadChange.emit({ active: false });
  }


// loading-bar.component.ts

....
export class LoadingbarComponent {

  constructor(loader: LoadingService) {

    this.loader.onLoadChange.subscribe((event) => {
      // do logic with your loading bar here
    }

  }

}
```

Now for getting everything loaded before the page is displayed, that is going to be *tough*. You can look into progressive web apps, but the thing is there is no `onPageReady` event to fire when the content is not yet in the DOM. What you can do is look into the router's `resolve` method, which is defined in the route definition. The `resolve` function (or service) will need to return true before Angular will load the page. So, for example, you can fetch large images or ajax data when the route is clicked, but delay the page displaying until the data is actually there.

**Note** I would *not* consider this as a best practice, as usually you want the page to change as fast as possible. Humans perceive many short waits (like a page loading content) much differently than a single longer wait (like taking 1.5s to change pages). Either way, more info on `resolve` is available [in this excellent article.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html)

Good luck!